# Symfony2/PHP array of Objects

Tags: php, symfony

I have been trying to move some legacy code into Symfony2 but have come to something which has stumped me.  I have a function

```
public function findSeatsOnFlights($allInfo, $flights, $seatCodes)
{
}
```

In both the legacy and my new code, $allInfo is the same format so do not need to worry about this.  In my legacy code, if I var_dump $flights and $seatCodes, I get something like

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(3) "VS7"
  [1]=> string(3) "VS8"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(1) "C"
  [1]=> string(1) "D"
}
```

To handle this, I would do

```
public function findSeatsOnFlights($allInfo, $flights, $seatCodes){
    $answer = array( );

    foreach ( $flights as $flight )
    {
        $finfo = $allInfo[ $flight ];

        $fseats = $finfo["seats"];

        foreach ( $seatCodes as $code )
        {

        }
    }
}
```

However, with Symfony2, my var_dump of $flights and $seatCodes is

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[405]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlertFlightNumbers' (length=55)
      public 'id' => int 52
      public 'flightNumber' => string 'VS7' (length=3)
      public 'availabilityAlert' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert' (length=42)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[406]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlertFlightNumbers' (length=55)
      public 'id' => int 53
      public 'flightNumber' => string 'VS8' (length=3)
      public 'availabilityAlert' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert' (length=42)

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[406]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlertBookingClass' (length=54)
      public 'id' => int 62
      public 'classLetter' => string 'C' (length=1)
      public 'availabilityAlert' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert' (length=42)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[404]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlertBookingClass' (length=54)
      public 'id' => int 63
      public 'classLetter' => string 'D' (length=1)
      public 'availabilityAlert' => string 'Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert' (length=42)
```

So how would I go about handling this instead?  I have tried things like this without success

```
foreach ( $flights as $flight )
{
    $finfo = $allInfo[ $flight->getFlightNumber() ];
    ....
```

If I do the above I get

> Warning: Illegal offset type (500 Internal Server Error)

So what is the best way of changing my code to now handle the Objects?

Comment: Try with `$finfo = $allInfo[ $flight->flightNumber ];` instead?

Comment: Wont allow me to do it that way, cant access a private property

Comment: It says 'public' in your var_dump... Alternatively, consider "converting" the stdClass into an array with `$flightArray = json_decode(json_encode($flight),true);`